# "Use of Unresolved Identifier" Error when Variable Declared in loadView()

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a simple app where when a user taps, the label text will change, as shown in the code below. However, in my function that handles the tap, it says that label is unresolved. I believe this is because the label is loaded in the loadView and cannot be accessed throughout the class (I am a beginner Swift user, so forgive me if I'm wrong.) Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let containerView = UIView (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "Hey"
        containerView.addSubview(label)
        self.view = containerView
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }
    @objc func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        label.text = "Changed"
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `label` as a local variable inside `loadView` - This means it is only accessible in the `loadView` function. You need it to be a property so that it is accessible throughout your class.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var label: UILabel!

    override func loadView() {
        let containerView = UIView (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        self.label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        self.label.textAlignment = .center
        self.label.text = "Hey"
        containerView.addSubview(self.label)
        self.view = containerView
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }
    @objc func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.label.text = "Changed"
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `label` which is declared within `loadView()` method. `handleTap()` does not have visibility/access to `label`.

Declare `label` as class variable.

Refer here for more information about declaration and scope: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html